# When to use #define or constant char/int?

Tags: c, constants, c-preprocessor

In general, is it better to define some specific parameters (e.g. `(char *) UserIPaddr="192.168.0.5"` ,  `(int) MAX_BUF=1024`) by `#define` or `constant char */ int`?

I read some threads say that it is better not to use `#define` when it is possible. However, I see quite common usage of `#define` on open source codes [one example](https://github.com/qca/open-ath9k-htc-firmware/blob/master/target_firmware/wlan/ieee80211_output.c) from a source code:

```
#define IEEE80211_WLAN_HDR_LEN      24
    a_uint8_t *iv = NULL;
    a_uint16_t tmp;
    a_uint16_t offset = IEEE80211_WLAN_HDR_LEN;
```

`#define` could be avoided to use there, but I wonder why it was preferred to use #define on that case for example. How should I decide when to use `#define` or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C const declarations do not produce constant expressions, So if you need to have a constant expression its not possible using `const`, the traditional and more commonly used way to do so is using `# define`.

For example `const int` cannot be used in:

- a case label or
- as a bit-field width or
- as array size in a non-VLA array declaration (pre C99 days)

Answer (score 3):

There are few reasons to use `#define`. There is little it accomplishes that a `static const` or `enum` cannot.

As Alok Save mentions, `static const int` cannot produce an integral constant expression in C (I'm not double checking the C standard; it isn't the case in C++ though). But `enum` can do that. However `enum` in pure C does not grow to accommodate values larger than `INT_MAX`. So if you need a `long` value to use as an array bound or case label, `#define` is your friend. Or consider switching to using the C subset of C++, which doesn't have such restrictions.

Comment: for switch, it's better to use enums, so the compiler warns you if some case is not being handled.

Answer (score 2):

My rule of thumb is to not use `#define` unless the symbol must be a compile-time constant. With this in mind, I personally would not have used `#define` in your example.

To take a different example from [the same source file](https://github.com/qca/open-ath9k-htc-firmware/blob/master/target_firmware/wlan/ieee80211_output.c):

```
#define CRYPTO_KEY_TYPE_AES          2
...
    switch (keytype) {
    case CRYPTO_KEY_TYPE_AES:
```

Here, `CRYPTO_KEY_TYPE_AES` must be a constant expression, and thus using a constant variable would not do.